# Is there a Google Sheets or MS Excel formula to convert a column with JSON array to multiple rows

Tags: json, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to parse a column with JSON array data in an Excel file. I want to convert that JSON array to multiple rows.

I've tried using split text to columns, but that is giving inconsistent results.

Input:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image: 0]

You can find my input and expected_output sheet in this Google sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zohaZXEoppbn4GBq-BLEFHk5n4PPwYPOTnbZbq6YbNs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you thought about creating a script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are many ways one of which is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(C2:C, ","))<>"", "♦"&A2:A&"♠"&B2:B&"♠"&
 REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(C2:C, """", ), ","), ":(\d+)"), ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99)), "♦")), "♠"))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(LEN(A2), "♦"&A2&"♠"&B2&QUERY(TRANSPOSE("♠"&QUERY(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(C2, """", ), "{")), ","), ":(\d+)"), "offset 1", 0))
 ,,999^99), )),,999^99)),,999^99)), "♦")), "♠"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: How does this work? Will it also support this JSON array if it had multiple keys per object?

Comment: When using this formula with a JSON having multiple keys per object then it is splitting them into multiple rows instead of multiple columns

Comment: thank you for your help and it is working with multiple columns now. But it is only working with integer values and not working with string values. I have updated the google sheet. I am accepting your answer but if you could please help with this, I'll be grateful. Thanks

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(LEN(A2), "♦"&A2&"♠"&B2&QUERY(TRANSPOSE("♠"&QUERY(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(C2, """|]|}", ), "{")), ","), ":(.+)"), "offset 1", 0))
 ,,999^99), )),,999^99)),,999^99)), "♦")), "♠"))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/URIXN.png

Answer (score 3):

One may adopt the code from my project.

[json](/questions/tagged/json) is a tricky format, it uses different data types and also may contain nested items:

```
{ key: { key1: "a", key2: "b" } }
```

This is the reason to use [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) for the task.

Please, [copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/156FszF2onktVZEr_8OMPpkKZZpZlXCMPxJ-IUaLUZUI/copy) the sample file:

or see the source code here:

https://github.com/Max-Makhrov/GoogleSheets/blob/master/Json.gs

Sample usage:

`=getJsonArrayAsTable(C2)`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I needed to do something similar today in Google Sheets. The solution I came up with is surprisingle simple. It may be useful but has a couple of dependencies:

- The JSON data conforms to a Google Apps Script Range-like structure (examples below)**.
- A [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) defined using Google Apps Script.

**The custom function**

```
function JSONTOJS(JSONString) {
  return JSON.parse(JSONString);
}
```

**Sample Data**

A simple list:

```
["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]
```

Tabular data:

```
[["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"], ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"], ["Option 5", "Option 6", "Option 7", "Option 8"]]
```

Key:value pairs:

```
[["key1","value 1"], ["key2","value 2"], ["key3","value 3"]]
```

**In use:**
Assuming one of these JSON strings was in cell A1, in some other cell input the following formula and the data will be displayed in the cells in your Sheet.

```
=JSONTOJS(A1)
```

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z06MC-k3WmbmqkhBlwwGe7F_mn_Juke2uV8jWq1gYRs/edit?usp=sharing) ([get a copy of it](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z06MC-k3WmbmqkhBlwwGe7F_mn_Juke2uV8jWq1gYRs/copy))

** If you're defining the data structure, this may be useful. You're unlikely to receive data from some service in this format (it is quite Google Sheets unique), in which case your mileage will vary.

[google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)